# Error parsing parameter '--targets': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input: '[Key:InstanceIds]'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

```
aws ssm send-command --document-name "arn:aws:ssm:---" --targets \'[{"Key":"InstanceIds","Values":['"$instance_id"']}]\' --parameters \'{}\' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --region us-east-1
```

just trying to execute this command and yet i get the error about the

```
Error parsing parameter '--targets': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input: '[Key:InstanceIds]'
```

any assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong format for the `--targets` argument.

It should instead be formatted as the below syntax as seen in the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html).

```
--targets "Key=instanceids,Values=$instance_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you eliminate the white spaces as they interrupt the parsing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).